# Sql Server Distinct One Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I need one value from distinct query in MS SQL Server.
You can see, I created query but result has two value in "ManifestNo" is 5. 
If "ManifestNo" column include "A", write "A" else write "B".

Thanks for your support.

```
SELECT distinct a.ManifestNo ,CASE WHEN a.[Active]='A' THEN 'A' ELSE 'P' END AS ActiveState
FROM [YOTK_WH_Trace].[dbo].[Orders] as a INNER JOIN RefTable as b ON a.WEBARD1_PARTNO = b.UrunNo
where  [ManifestYear]=2017 and [ManifestMonth]=02 and [ManifestDay]=13 and (b.State = 1)
order by a.ManifestNo
```

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/611Xr.jpg)

```
ManifestNo  ActiveState
1           P
2           A
3           A
4           A
5           A
5           P
6           A
```

I Need below table:

```
ManifestNo  ActiveState
1           P
2           A
3           A
4           A
5           A
6           A
```

Comment: Please, use formatted text for table data - not images.

Comment: There are 2 distinct values of `(MinifestNo, ActiveState)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Distinct keyword and use `GROUP BY` clause and `MIN` aggregate function

```
 SELECT a.ManifestNo ,MIN(CASE WHEN a.[Active]='A' THEN 'A' ELSE 'P' END) AS ActiveState
 FROM [YOTK_WH_Trace].[dbo].[Orders] as a 
 INNER JOIN RefTable as b ON a.WEBARD1_PARTNO = b.UrunNo
 where  [ManifestYear]=2017 and [ManifestMonth]=02 and [ManifestDay]=13 and (b.State = 1)
 GROUP BY a.ManifestNo
 order by a.ManifestNo
```

Comment: Wooouuw.! Thank you !! You save my day :) I love "StackOverFlow" !!

Answer (score 1):

other solution

```
select * from (
    SELECT a.ManifestNo ,CASE WHEN a.[Active]='A' THEN 'A' ELSE 'P' END AS ActiveState,
    row_number() over(partition by  a.ManifestNo order by CASE WHEN a.[Active]='A' THEN 'A' ELSE 'P' END) as rang
    FROM [YOTK_WH_Trace].[dbo].[Orders] as a INNER JOIN RefTable as b ON a.WEBARD1_PARTNO = b.UrunNo
    where  [ManifestYear]=2017 and [ManifestMonth]=02 and [ManifestDay]=13 and (b.State = 1)
) tmp
where tmp.rang=1
order by tmp.ManifestNo
```